# TextFlow to TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

У меня стоит задача, консоль вывода, которая реализована на `TextFlow`, должна быть выделяема, т.е. я должен иметь возможность копировать сообщения оттуда. Выбрал путь через `TextArea` и столкнулся с проблемой узлов. Если есть предложения, как мне сделать `TextFlow` выделяемой - буду благодарен!

Так вот, в `TextFlow` добавление сообщения было следующим:

```
public void addNewMessage(ConsoleMessage message) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (message != null) {
                _console.getChildren().add(getText(message));
                moveScrollToBottom();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

А в `TextArea` я сделал так:

```
@Override
public void addNewMessage(ConsoleMessage message) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (message != null) {
                _console.appendText(message.getMessage());
                _console.setStyle(MessageType.getCSSForStatus(message.getType()));
                moveScrollToBottom();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Как можно заметить, у меня все в одном узле, потому что я не могу понять, как мне добавить узлы в `TextArea`. Это является проблемой, т.к. у меня сообщения с разными стилями (цвета разные) и как только я добавляю сообщение другого стиля, все предыдущие становятся другого стиля.

Comment: TextArea не поддерживает форматирование отдельных элементов текста. либо весь, либо ничего. Вроде бы моно заменить RichText компонентом, название не помню, либо вообще сделать Html